# Convert page to Indic Scripts

Tags: android, localization, custom-font, indic

I just created a text page in my app and now i want to change language of this page dynamically 
to Indian languages like Telugu, Tamil, Bengla, Guujrati and Punjabi.

I researched a lot, and got that there are only 2 methods to achieve this(please correct me if i am going wrong):-

1)Using localization of strings http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html .
    But in it problem is that, if android phone is supportable with these languages then it works 
    otherwise it show boxes in-place of fonts.

2)Using custom fonts to change language like

```
 TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom);
 Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Verdana.ttf");
 tv.setTypeface(face);
```

But here's the problem is rendering. Fonts are not rendered properly.

Please suggest me, which option should i choose and how to overcome it's limitation.

I also want to mention that I want to support it on Android 2.3 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Android 3, you need to use an appropriate font plus localisation to display characters from special scripts.

For Android 3+, using localisation most times is sufficient. Exceptions are Arabic, Hebrew, Indic scripts and a few others where you may need an appropriate font in addition to localisation to properly display these special characters in your Android app.

AFAIK, **Verdana** ONLY supports **European Scripts** such as **Latin-1**, **Latin Extended-A**, **Latin Extended-B**, **Latin Extended Additional**, **Basic Greek** and **Cyrillic**. Whereas Telugu, Tamil, Bengali, Gujarati are part of the **South Asian Scripts** - not sure about Punjabi (See [Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) for more info regarding Unicode scripts.) I guess you need to find an open-source font (so you don't have to pay loyalty when using proprietary fonts) that support the scripts you want to implement in your app.